# How do I create this directory using this function? I keep getting an access denied error.(C#)

Tags: c#, file, directory

First, let me begin by saying I know this appears to be a commonly asked question, but trust me, I've searched extensively and I couldn't find the answer to my question specifically. IF you do happen to know where this specific question was asked, by all means, mark it as a duplicate and reference me there, and accept my apologies for not finding it.

Now, I have a simple if function in my code:

```
 if (!Directory.Exists(FileDirectory))
 {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(FileDirectory);
 }
```

However, upon running this if Function, I get this error code:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\LockingProgram\Password.txt;' is denied.'

Now, obviously the problem is that the access is denied. How would I gain access?
I have tried simply writing the file instantly, however then it won't find the path

```
File.WriteAllText(FileDirectory, Password);
```

throws this error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\LockingProgram\Password.txt;'

The `FileDirectory` string is:

```
 string FileDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\LockingProgram\\Password.txt;";
```

Currently, what the program is trying to do is get a password from the user when they click a button, and then saves that password to a txt file located at the file directory for future reference. When they open the program, it checks if the file exists. If it exists, it sets the password to that file, and if it doesn't it forces the user to enter a string into a text box and from there, I am trying to save it. However, that's where I'm having the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I now understand it's generally a bad idea to save it to `Program Files`, and you should use `AppData` instead. I'll try that and update you if it works that time.

Edit 2: It now works. I changed the file directory to:

```
string FileDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "LockingApp";
```

And I added a new variable:

```
string FileName = "Password.txt";
```

And I modified where the directory is created to:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(FileDirectory))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(FileDirectory);
}

File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(FileDirectory, FileName), Password);
```

Thanks for your help guys! Hopefully I formatted this question well.

Comment: You typically dont have access to `C:\Program Files\` It is a bad idea to try to store data there, anyway.,  There are AppData and User folders just for that

Comment: Alright, my bad. I assumed it was just a place to store Program Files.

Comment: Use `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolders.LocalApplicationData), "LockingProgram")` for storing data under `C:\users\[current user]\appdata\local\lockingprogram`

Comment: Well, previously using this code I saved it to C:\ and it worked fine. Then I figured I should use Program Files and it stopped working. I tried going back to C:\ and that time it wouldn't work, so I was pretty confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\\Program Files\\LockingProgram\\Password.txt;
```

is not a directory, use

```
FileDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\LockingProgram";

Directory.CreateDirectory(FileDirectory);
```

Also there is a probably a good chance you will need to run your program at an elevated privilege or with the appropriate permissions, i.e as an administrator

However there are better places to store data

[Where Should I Store my Data and Configuration Files if I Target Multiple OS Versions?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/)

ie *AppData*, for example

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Comment: Well, I got a question. I've saved it to app data, as you said to do. The program recognizes it and everything, it'll read and write data to it and everything. However, when I go to the exact same file directory in windows explorer it doesn't exist...... Which means I can't reset the password which is currently set to null.

Comment: @NicholaiRen Make sure you have turned on hidden folders in explorer, make sure you are looking at exactly the right path, it will be there if you are reading and writing to it. try debugging your code with a breakpoint, and inspecting the variable. just to make you sure you are looking at the right path

Comment: Hidden files is turned on, I can see AppData. I used Console.WriteLine(FileDirectory) and then copied the directory directly into FileExplorer, and it said "Windows can't find"

Comment: @NicholaiRen this maybe another question, maybe put all the facts, in another question with your exmaple code, and what you are experiencing

Comment: Figured it out. I guess. I'm not really sure. I just went in and changed the name of the FileDirectory from: 'string FileDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "LockingApp";'  to: 'string FileDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\LockingApp\\";'

Answer (score 1):

You can use Isolated Storage for saving files (Seems the easiest and least tasking to use).
Check this code sample below

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

public class CreatingFilesDirectories
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null))
    {
      isoStore.CreateDirectory("TopLevelDirectory");
      isoStore.CreateDirectory("TopLevelDirectory/SecondLevel");
      isoStore.CreateDirectory("AnotherTopLevelDirectory/InsideDirectory");
      Console.WriteLine("Created directories.");

      isoStore.CreateFile("InTheRoot.txt");
      Console.WriteLine("Created a new file in the root.");

      isoStore.CreateFile("AnotherTopLevelDirectory/InsideDirectory/HereIAm.txt");
      Console.WriteLine("Created a new file in the InsideDirectory.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just adapt for your use.